# Checking .BATs exit code with NAGIOS?

Tags: scripting, nagios, batch, windows-command-prompt

I currently have the following script on a Windows Server:

```
@echo off
set path=%PATH%;C:\UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin

cd /D Z:\videos

forfiles /M *_1.mkv /D +%date% > C:\mkv.txt >NUL 2>&1
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%B IN ('grep -c _1.mkv c:\mkv.txt') DO SET VIDEOS=%%B

if %VIDEOS% GEQ 1 (
echo "BAD VIDEOS!"
exit /B 0
) else (
echo "Videos OK"
exit /B 1 )
```

I need Nagios to check if the scripts exit code is 0 or 1 to diplay a critical alert or a ok. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that's what Nagios does. You need to return the correct [return codes](http://nagiosplug.sourceforge.net/developer-guidelines.html#AEN76), though. You'll probably have to change your script like this:

```
if %VIDEOS% GEQ 1 (
  echo "BAD VIDEOS!"
  exit /B 2
) else (
  echo "Videos OK"
  exit /B 0
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I also had a problem on this " >NUL 2>&1 ". So the mkv.txt file what never filled. Now it is working.